# how can i access webservice using auth header

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx, soapheader

How do i access this webservice. I.I am new for this field.I have a service with authentication function. Please help me to access this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <MQUserNameToken xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <User_id>string</User_id>
      <Password>string</Password>
      <ExternalPartyName>string</ExternalPartyName>
    </MQUserNameToken>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCustomerInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CustomerInfoXML>string</CustomerInfoXML>
      <ReferenceNo>string</ReferenceNo>
    </GetCustomerInfo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please specify the programming language you are working in. If just want to access the webservice manually i guess you could use http://www.soapui.org/

Comment: I need the code in c#

Answer (score 0):

Configure ur envelope's headerOut

```
    envelope.headerOut= new Element[1];
    envelope.headerOut[0] = buildAuthHeader(user_id,pwd,externalPartyName);
```

Define the buildAuthHeader Method as follows

```
private Element buildAuthHeader(String user_id, String pwd, String externalPartyName) {

        Element h = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE,"MQUserNameToken");
        Element username = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "User_id");   
        username.addChild(Node.TEXT,user_id);
        h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, username);

        Element password = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "Password");
        password.addChild(Node.TEXT,pwd);
        h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, password);

        Element externalParty= new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "ExternalPartyName");
        pass.addChild(Node.TEXT,externalPartyName);
        h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, ExternalPartyName);
        }
        return h;
}
```